# При парсинге возвращается список элементов lxml, когда нужен лишь один элемент

Tags: python, парсер, lxml

Вот часть кода:

```
# Получаю список всех товаров со страницы
all_products = tree.xpath(
    '//div[@class="iva-item-content-m2FiN"]'
)

for product in all_products:
    
    title = product.xpath( 
        '//h3/text()'
    )
```

Вот что в all_products:

```
[<Element div at 0x7fe88a623db0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a623d60>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a623c20>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a623ea0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a623b30>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a623f40>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a623f90>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f040>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f090>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f0e0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f130>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f180>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f1d0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f220>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f270>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f2c0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f310>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f360>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f3b0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f400>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f450>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f4a0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f4f0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f540>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f590>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f5e0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f630>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f680>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f6d0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f720>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f770>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f7c0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f810>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f860>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f8b0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f900>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f950>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f9a0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62f9f0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fa40>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fa90>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fae0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fb30>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fb80>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fbd0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fc20>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fc70>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fcc0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fd10>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fd60>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fdb0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fe00>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fe50>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fea0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62fef0>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62ff40>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a62ff90>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a630040>, <Element div at 0x7fe88a630090>]
```

В цикле я прохожусь по полученным продуктам и пытаюсь получить с одной итерации одно название продукта. Вместо этого я получаю список названий всех продуктов на странице за одну итерацию.

Как получать одно название товара за одну итерацию вместо списка всех названий товаров со старницы за одну итерацию?

Comment: можете указать в вопросе кусочек `all_products`? что там лежит?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Загляните [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14896302/10562663). Мне кажется, что здесь будет ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону getchildren() для элемента и берите нужный вам тег например по индексу